# Accessing Clustered MSMQ with an application

Tags: cluster-computing, msmq

We are switching from a non-clustered to a 2-node clustered MSMQ Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Enterprise environment. Previously, when it was non-clustered, we wrote a .NET 3.5 C# Windows Form application to help us manage our environment (so it does tasks such as create queues with the right permissions, read messages, forward messages, etc.). I would like to make this application work with our new cluster.

Per these articles, 
http://blog.terranspot.com/2011/07/accessing-microsoft-message-queuing.html 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/18/clustering-msmq-applications-rule-1.aspx

I understand that I need to add the application as a resource on the cluster as when I don't, I am accessing the node's MSMQ instance. To help with my debugging, I have turned the local MSMQ services off. No matter what I do, however, the program keeps trying to access the node's instance. I added it as an application resource (with the command line of "Q:\QueueManagerConsole.exe". The Q:\ is the disk that is shared between the 2 nodes that is part of the failover cluster), but when I run it via Windows Explorer, it doesn't see the cluster instance, only the local. I have seen no way to execute a program from Failover Cluster Manager, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I switched the code to access everything via "." (so MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".")), which, per my meager understanding is how you access the local queue. Could someone explain, preferably acting as if I had no clue what I was doing, on a. if this IS possible and b. HOW to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by creating a shortcut to the application and putting it on the server that was actually accessing the clustered queues.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did something similar a while ago. Try [deploy a service in a failover cluster](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/deploying-nservicebus-in-a-windows-failover-cluster/)
, it wokerd for me to:

- configure the app to use clustered msmq
- configure app as clustered resource
- configure the app to connect under host name
- set the permission set rquired for transpot

At least this will give you a good starting point.

Comment: This example is for a Windows Service, not a Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

Please try add to environment used by Your application following Environment variables:

_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_
_CLUSTER_NETWORK_HOSTNAME_

with cluster server name as a value. It worked in the system which is being developed by my team - it contains a few services which had to access clustered MSMQ and it solved the problem.